# Billing error in publishing the application in android market

Tags: android, google-play

I have made an application and want to release it in android market using google play.But whenever i choose the billing option,it does not show the option india in the choose your country option.Please tell me how to solve this problem.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is an off-topic question on Stack Overflow. Consider voting for the [App Store](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30702/app-stores) site proposal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot *sell* apps on Google play from India. Check out the [List of supported locations for merchants](http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=150324)

Comment: So what is the solution sir.How can i do that

Comment: @user1551338 you might be looking into other options to monetize your app, such as ads..btw am also from India and looking into this matter. I am planning to incorporate a company in US and sell the app.